# calling a function as data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im just getting started on d3.js and was going through Nick's source code on github [here](https://github.com/NickQiZhu/d3-cookbook/blob/master/src/chapter3/function-as-data.html) and got stuck at the part where he is passing a function as data into d3.js.

The `var x` in the function assigned to `next var` gets incremented from 0 to the `loop counter` as i show in the jsbin link below. I cant quite wrap my head around how x gets incremented automatically and how does it know the loop counter that it needs to get incremented upto everytime.

> > the `next variable` is called from >> `newdata` from the >>`render function` ?

I just setup a jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/vinamerafa/1/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
.data(newData);
```

is simply going to call the `newData` function and bind the return to the selection.

So each call to `render` in the `setInterval` simply pushes the `next` function into his `data` array.

This part then:

```
selection.attr("class", "v-bar")
    .style("height", function (d, i) {
        return d(i) + "px"; // <- E
    })
    .select("span")
        .text(function(d, i){ 
            return d(i); // <- F
    });
```

Calls `d` which is the `next` function for each element in the data array. It's passing the index position in the `data` array.

So the first `render` call is:

```
 15 + 0 * 0;
```

Second is:

```
 15 + 0 * 0;
 15 + 1 * 1;
```

Third is:

```
 15 + 0 * 0;
 15 + 1 * 1;
 15 + 2 * 2;
```

Comment: perfect - i from d(i) gets routed into x in the function defined on next ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, for simplification, this

```
var selection = d3.select("#container").selectAll("div")
  .data(newData); // <- D
```

is just like writing

```
var arrayOfFunctions = newData();
var selection = d3.select("#container").selectAll("div")
  .data(arrayOfFunctions); // <- D
```

So, for example, calling this code 3 times (via setInterval) builds up `arrayOfFunctions` like this:

```
arrayOfFunctions = [
  function (x) { return 15 + x * x; },
  function (x) { return 15 + x * x; },
  function (x) { return 15 + x * x; }
]
```

(Note: it's not literally like that, because in actuality they're just pointers to the same function `next`)

So nothing about that increments `x`. But once it binds those functions to DOM elements (via `data(arrayOfFunctions)` and runs through this bit:

```
    selection.attr("class", "v-bar")
        .style("height", function (d, i) {
            return d(i) + "px"; // <- E
        })
```

`d` is `function (x) { return 15 + x * x; }` and `i` (which is 0, 1, or 2) is passed in as `x` to that function when it calls `d(i)`.

And that's what essentially increments `x`.